# What is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n\frac{k}{n^2}$?

Tags: limits

We have $$\dfrac{1+2+3+...+ \space n}{n^2}$$

What is the limit of this function as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

My idea:

$$\dfrac{1+2+3+...+ \space n}{n^2} = \dfrac{1}{n^2} + \dfrac{2}{n^2} + ... + \dfrac{n}{n^2} = 0$$

Is this correct?

Comment: When you break it down in terms, each individual term goes to zero, but their number goes to infinity. Thus, in "limit", you get infinitely many zeroes, or in other words $\infty \cdot 0$... But this can be anything....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT:

Such application of limit (esp. to $\infty$) to individual summand is applicable only when the number of summand is finite.

$$\dfrac{1+2+3+...+ \space n}{n^2} =\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}2}{n^2}=\frac12\cdot\left(1+\frac1n\right)$$

Comment: So it is $\dfrac{1}{2}$. I however don't understand why my method is wrong, and also your first step eludes me

Comment: You seem to be trying to use the sum rule for sequences - this only works when the number of terms in the sum is constant, but in this case it grows with $n$. The first step in this answer is the result $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$.

Comment: @LimitsMate, please find the explanation in the answer

Comment: @LimitsMate, 
For example $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\ne 1$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Coincidentally I know that's $e$. Wow, that's the best counterexample you could have given lol

Comment: @LimitsMate, could I make the idea clear?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes, thanks, although the idea is hard for me to fathom. Is there perhaps a formal proof to your first statement?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: I'm a bit puzzled about the (added) first sentence and the interversion limit/sum (the way it is phrased, I'm not sure it is correct -- see for instance the theorems for series of functions when you have uniform convergence — or even that I understand the statement —as "$n$" is used as a summation indice (I assume) _and_ upper bound (ditto))

Comment: @ClementC., how about the re-phrased version?

Comment: Seems fine to me :)

Answer (score 8):

Another method, using Riemann sums applied to $f:x\mapsto x$:
$$
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k }{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k }{n}  \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}
\int_{0}^{1} xdx
$$

As for your question, each term goes to $0$, *but* the number of terms grows; you are not in the case where you have the sum of "constantly many terms, each of them converging".

Comment: But there will never be a term which doesn't go to 0 right?

Comment: Yes, but since you get an increasing number of them, it can balance this fact.
As a naive counter example, write $1=n\cdot\frac 1 n = \frac 1 n+\dots+\frac 1 n$. You have $n$ terms, each of them goes to $0$; yet the sum is always $1$.

Comment: Clear example, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Recall that $$1 + 2 + \cdots + n =\sum_{i = 1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

So you want $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2n^2} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+ n}{2n^2} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac 12 + \frac 1{2n}\right)$$

Comment: I'd recall it if I knew it, I however didn't and I also don't like to recall stuff in math unless I understand what I'm recalling, which in this case I do not.

Comment: I just use "recall" out of habit. There is a nice link in Wikipedia about sums like this one: [summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums#Some_summations_of_polynomial_expressions)

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be of greater help in answering your questions. The sum of the first n terms, as used in this problem, is a special case of an [arithmetic progression/series.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_series)

Comment: Well, that comment helped me a lot. Arithmetic progressions..that's what Gauss used in his famous anecdote right? That was a real eye-opener!

Comment: Exactly: This is a case of exactly what Gauss used in the famous anecdote we all love!

Comment: Nice interchange too! +1

Answer (score 1):

Your method is wrong. Consider the first values of the expression:

- for $n=1$ you get $1$;
- for $n=2$ you get $1/4+2/4=3/4$;
- for $n=3$ yoy get $1/9+2/9+3/9=6/9=2/3$.

One could make the conjecture that these terms are always bigger than $1/2$, which can be proved by induction. Let
$$
f(n)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n i
$$
We have $f(1)=1>1/2$. Suppose the assertion holds for $f(n)$ and consider
\begin{align}
f(n+1)&=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i\\
&=\biggl(\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} i\biggr)+\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\biggl(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n i\biggr)+\frac{1}{n+1}\\
\text{(by induction hypothesis)}\qquad&>\frac{1}{2}\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{n+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{n^2+2n+2}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\biggl(\frac{n^2+2n+1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\biggr)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\biggl(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\biggr)\\
&>\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
Therefore your conclusion that the limit is $0$ cannot be true.